# how to update the database from a server when the app is not running in Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I need to make a server call to fetch new data from the server and then update the app database, and this has to be done when the app is not running.
so I try to get set up a alarm manager in the onCreate() in the main activity to call a `UpdateService.java`:

```
        Intent asdas = new Intent(MyActivity.this,
                UpdateService.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                MyActivity.this, 0, asdas, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager)    getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr0.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 3000, 1000, pIntent);
```

and the `UpdateService.java` code:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Testing", "Service got started");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("Testing", "Service got started");
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

also in my manifest i have:

```
 <service
            android:name="com.secretescapes.update.UpdateService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":my_process" />
```

The problem is that I cant see the logs `Log.d("Testing", "Service got started");` in my LogCat. What is the problem and why this service is not started?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `getActivity` instead of `getService`?

Comment: thanks!!! that helped,now how do I make sure now that if I call this code again a new service won't be started?

Comment: You need to define a BroadCastReciever that receives the intent from alarm and from this receiver, you should attempt to start the service

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntentService, this class then have the code which will first check whether database is updated or not. If its not updated then you can write piece of code which will fetch data from server and update local database.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your service by using this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Regarding "the second instance" will be started:

Per docs: "Note that multiple calls to `Context.startService()` do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to `onStartCommand()`), so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped once `Context.stopService()` or `stopSelf()` is called;"

In other words the second instance of this service won't be created.

BTW, it's better to replace `setRepeating` with `setInexactRepeating`:

Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see `setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent)` and `setExact(int, long, PendingIntent)`. Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.